# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all() error in object detection

Tags: python, tensorflow2.0, object-detection-api

when exploring the object detection api, I get this error:

```
The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().
```

I'm not sure what to do next. I don't get this error if I send a boolean array but it is supposed to be a float value.

I have pasted my code below:

```
viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
    image=img,
    boxes=result['detection_boxes'],
    classes=result['detection_classes'] + label_id_offset,
    scores=result['detection_scores'],
    category_index=category_index,
    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
    min_score_thresh=0.8)
```

Comment: Please provide the full error traceback.

Comment: Usually this is caused when you're trying to get boolean values from an n-dimensional numpy array. This situation is ambiguous and you need to defined whether you data to be evaluated along rows `any(axis=0)` or along columns `any(axis=1)`. Or similarly with `all()`.

Comment: The said error is for the final line, min_score_thresh=0.8. That's a scalar right? Why is there an error then that's related to an array?

Comment: Please show the traceback.

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ff58eb8fa920> in <module>()
      7     category_index=category_index,
      8     use_normalized_coordinates=True,
----> 9     min_score_thresh=0.8)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py in __bool__(self)
    990 
    991   def __bool__(self):
--> 992     return bool(self._numpy())
    993 
    994   __nonzero__ = __bool__

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Please do **not** post code or error messages in the comments - they are literally unreadable! Edit & update your post instead.